# Yocto How we specify multiple download mirror for open source package

Tags: yocto

Generally, a package downloaded from open source hosting (such sourceforge) provides mirrors to download, How can we specify multiple mirror via Yocto recipe to fetch packages available on multiple links.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify with PREMIRRORS

```
PREMIRRORS_append = "\n http://www.jedsoft.org/releases/slang/.* http://www.jedsoft.org/releases/slang/old/ \n"
```

For reference : [slang recipe](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-extended/slang/slang_2.3.0.bb?h=morty#n29)  morty